# EJBCA API example

Tags: java, api, pki

I completely got lost. I have installed [`EJBCA`](http://ejbca.org/) on `CentOS` and the next task I have is to retrieve a certificates from the server using `C#` gui client (that will be installed on common PC).

Unfortunately, `EJBCA` supports only [`Java` API](http://ejbca.sourceforge.net/ws/overview-tree.html) (correct me, if I'm wrong). So the only option for me is to write a wrapper (library) in `Java` which will send the data to my client via JSON or whatever (`Apache Thrift`, for example).

But I have not written any code on `Java`. Also, I'm not familiar with the process of using Java API.

A tiny example would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: what kind of java example you want?

Comment: Just connect and retrieve all revoked certificates, for example. But it's a bit complicated. Would be enough a simple example - just connect and print some EJBCA specific information (home path, etc.). I need to catch the idea.

Answer (score 3):

EJBCA has plenty of interfaces. There is a Web Service interface that you can use from any remote client (client certificate authenticated). You can also get simple things like certificates and CRLs from simple http calls.
You can go to public web and and make the same simple HTTP GET call from your app. You can also enable the RFC4387 service and get CA certificates and CRLs using RFC4387 URLs, http://ejbca.org/services-va.html